# Andengine BitmapTextureAtlas

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine, game-engine

Is the `power of 2 rule` required in Andengine GLES2, or was it just for GLES1. I know it was recommended to create your BitmapTextureAtlas with width and height values as power of 2, `512x512` for example. But is this necessary? If yes, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that in GLES2 it's not required. I think/guess it's possible that some edge devices might not have full or complete implementations, so I still do it.

EDIT: "I still do it" as a general rule for production. During testing I have played with it being non power of 2 and it works fine on my devices.

Comment: Is there a performance gain when you are not using this rule? Is memory allocation considerably lower?

Comment: memory allocation is definitely affected - depending on the bitmaps used and size declared. For power of 2 usage, I never go above 1024x1024 as I have read others having issues above that - again, those issues are seemingly related to incomplete or non compliant implementations on some devices. I have not analyzed performance to see.

Comment: Thank your for you answer. Yes I know there are some problems, I had one with `2048` size but only on low-end phones.

Comment: Then what is the Best Way ? Using multiple Atlas with 1024 * 1024 if we want..other than altas's, with size greater values...

Comment: @jmroyalty first thanks for your answer. But I hav little confusion. If I used 1040 *1040 size for bitmapAtlas will it allocate 2048*2048 in memory.